# Cannot find function createEvent (or createAllDayEvent). (Google Spreadsheet App)

Tags: google-apps-script, google-calendar-api, spreadsheet

here is my code that is causing the error. It seems to be just the line where I attempt to add the all day event. What needs to change to correct the error, or what does the error actually mean.

```
function SpreadsheetToCalendar3() 
{
  // This function should be executed from the 
  //  spreadsheet you want to export to the calendar
  var mySpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("My Calendar-Sheet01");

  var myCalendar = CalendarApp.openByName("My Calendar-01");

  // optional - delete existing events
  var events = myCalendar.getEvents(new Date("November 1, 2018 EST"),
new Date("November 1, 2019 EST"));
  for (var i = 0; i < events.length; i++) 
  {
     events[i].deleteEvent();
  }

  var dataRange = mySpreadsheet.getRange("A2:B39");
  var data = dataRange.getValues();

  // process the data
  for (i in data) 
  {
      var row = data[i];
      // assume that each row contains a date entry and a text entry
      var theDate  = row[1];  // First column of row
      var theTitle = row[0];  // Second column of row
      myCalendar.createAllDayEvent(theTitle, theDate);
  }

}
```

Comment: Your comment describes row[1] as the first column but of course it's the second column. So maybe theTitle is a date and theDate is a title so you may be some sort of a type error.

Comment: the error says Cannot find method createAllDayEvent(string,string).

Comment: and my datas from sheet is that Event name, date(2018/12/21)

Comment: Yes it cannot find method createAllDayEvent(string,string) because your date is not a Date() and there is no method in the Calendar Class for createAllDayEvent that has two string parameters.  So I'd guess that your date is a string and note a Date().  Single step through the program and see for yourself.